# When new table is added in room db from version 1 to version 2

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, database-migration, android-room

I am using Room Persistance library which android has released as a alternative for SQLite Database.

I am currently having Android app on playstore with SQLite Database and While migrating app from SQLite to Room, I am facing several errors.

**First**

If I create new table do I need to write migration script i.e; I need to write migration query in Room everytime I upgrade the room version?

**Second**

I have the DB version on playstore with version of 20 and when I upgrade it to 21. Do I need to write migration scripts from 1 to 20 and 20 to 21 or only from 20 to 21.

Because I don't know what app db version does user have (production app), it can be 10,12, 15. How will the migration scripts be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Every time you add a table (or make any schema change) you need to either a) add a migration or b) call .`fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` ONLY IF YOU DON'T CARE ABOUT PERSISTING THE DATA. Check out https://medium.com/google-developers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929 for more.
2. You'll need to write a migration script for every database your user could be on to upgrade them to 21 (again, unless you don't care about persisting data, in which case you can use `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`). This above link should also address this question.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that is correct but the fallback method will just destory all my data and new tables will be created...

Comment: correct, so the other option is then yes, you'll have to write scripts for each database to 21